# Multiple level bindings with DataTemplate based on type

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate

I'm trying to make a complicated template for ListBox item, but some bindings not working or "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath." exception occurred.

I have a ListBox binding on ObservableCollection of CustomerViewModel. Each item in ListBox must display two properties of CustomerViewModel object. The first one is "Name" (type - string), and second one is "Value" (type - object). Real type of "Value" can be: bool, int, string, datetime, so the control template for displaying must be select-able.

**Code of "Value" property:**

```
    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            switch (this.info.InputType)
            {
                case Enums.InputType.DateTime:
                    return Convert.ToDateTime(this.info.Value);

                case Enums.InputType.Logical:
                    return Convert.ToBoolean(this.info.Value);

                case Enums.InputType.Numeric:
                    return Convert.ToInt32(this.info.Value);

                case Enums.InputType.Text:
                    return this.info.Value;
            }
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        set
        {
            this.info.Value = value.ToString();
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>                           
        <StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Value}">
                        <ContentControl.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:Boolean}">
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:Int32}">
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:DateTime}">
                                <DatePickerTextBox Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ContentControl.Resources>
                    </ContentControl>
                </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

XAML below throws "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath" exception, because of

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Value}">
```

and

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding}"/>
```

If I change last line to:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
```

..there are no exceptions, but binding works only "OneWay".
I think, I need, somehow, to bind TextBox to same property - "Value" as ContentControl, but I can't perform TwoWay binding in this case.

Could it be done like this without writing of ItemTemplateSelector?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried your last line with setting the mode?

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**EDIT**:

I noticed you are using this.**fieldInfo**.Value in the get and this.**info**.Value in the set, is this just a typo?

Are you sure you are not able to hit a break point placed in your set?

**EDIT**:

Hmm, I'm running out of ideas, maybe you could try setting the update source trigger?:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Yes! It didn't help, binding is still OneWay.

Comment: Yes, sorry. That was just a typo - fixed. 
Exactly - I can't hit the break point in "Value" setter. I made a small changes to test bindings:

..
<Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
**<TextBox x:Name="testTextBox" Text="{Binding Value}"/>**
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Value}">
..
</ContentControl>
..

If I start typing in the "testTextBox" then breakpoint hits, and string in coresponding control (inside of ContentControl) also changed! But not in backward direction.